# File "/home/roopasree/Desktop/aiml/face.py", line 54, in <module> face_encodings=face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame,face_locations)

Tags: python, aiml

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roopasree/Desktop/aiml/face.py", line 54, in <module>
    face_encodings=face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame,face_locations)
  File "/home/roopasree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 214, in face_encodings
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
  File "/home/roopasree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 214, in <listcomp>
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x7f71fb725170>, array([[[239, 233, 241],
        [238, 237, 241],
        [240, 240, 238],
        ...,
        [155, 156, 152],
        [140, 128, 125],
        [153, 151, 139]],

       [[239, 234, 240],
        [236, 234, 238],
        [240, 238, 242],
        ...,
        [148, 147, 142],
        [128, 119, 112],
        [167, 165, 152]],

       [[238, 236, 238],
        [233, 233, 232],
        [233, 233, 232],
        ...,
        [133, 128, 123],
        [157, 153, 146],
        [171, 169, 160]],

       ...,

       [[ 58,  34,  40],
        [ 60,  40,  44],
        [ 60,  40,  44],
        ...,
        [ 22,  20,  20],
        [ 50,  44,  40],
        [ 46,  41,  40]],

       [[ 66,  40,  44],
        [ 69,  46,  45],
        [ 68,  46,  41],
        ...,
        [  7,   7,   6],
        [ 24,  24,  22],
        [ 32,  34,  32]],

       [[ 65,  40,  43],
        [ 69,  45,  43],
        [ 74,  53,  46],
        ...,
        [  8,   6,   4],
        [ 21,  21,  19],
        [ 35,  37,  34]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x7f71fb619930>, 1
```

This the problem i face